# Using Knockout to bind different models to different sections on a page

Tags: knockout.js

I'm using knockout javascript library in my asp.net application.

For knockout I use **ko** object and **applyBindings()** method to bind it. Now I want to bind two knockout object to two different user interface section. How can I use have second knockout object or have second datasource so I can use it in my second section?

Comment: can you provide a *concrete* case where you need this, probably with some code examples?

Comment: Consider this example: http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving   As you see it use ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel()); code to bind data. Now I have another section in my page which use another object and another loading/saving data from server. How to do second one as it seems there is only one object of knockout available to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily apply different bindings to different parts of the HTML code.

If you have a structure such as this:

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Just do something like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, document.getElementById('one'));
ko.applyBindings(viewModelTwo, document.getElementById('two'));
```

If you have a structure such as this:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

You can use the `controlsDescendantBindings` flag to tell knockout to leave a certain child element alone. Use this in a custom binding such as the one below:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinding = {
    init: function() {
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
<div id="one">
    <div data-bind="stopBinding: true">
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I surrounded the 2nd div with the stopBinding function. This allows you to call the same applyBindings code like so:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModelOne, document.getElementById('one'));
ko.applyBindings(viewModelTwo, document.getElementById('two'));
```

Reference: http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html

Comment: you've forgot `)` at the end in all four `applyBindings` calls.

Comment: Edited, thanks. That's what happens when you answer stuff at 3 in the morning.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know about `controlsDescendantBindings`.